# GSA Lotus Connector

Tags: ibm-domino, connector, gsa

I'm trying to install a connector for GSA to crawl a Domino server.

It required me to - create a GSAConn.nsf database that contains configuration for GSA Connector (based on a template file). - Create an user with access MANAGER to the GSAConn.nsf

A tomcat server will run the connector and GSA will connect to Tomcat to collect data.

So far, I have been struggling with the error:

Note Exception: example/server/domino !!GSAConn.nsf has not been opened yet.

From my understanding this either mean the GSA can't find the GSAConn.nsf or the user does not have access to GSAConn.nsf, but I'm sure that the created user have full access to GSAConn.nsf

Many thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas which might cause that:

1.)
The DB isn´t fully initialized. That means only a replication stub is created on the server. Can you open the server example and the GSAConn.nsf on it? Did you got a error message?

2.)
It might also that the server "Example" couldn´t be found. If you ping "Example" on the server where the error message appears did that work? If yes, then check if the connection which is used by GSA works (e.g. if a Notes client is required, open the notes client and try to browse the server from it).